# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException while mocking java.util.Properties using easymock

Tags: unit-testing, easymock

I am using easymock framework to write UT's. I have one class which uses java.util.Properties in public function. Below is sample code:

```
public URI generateSASURI() throws CloudStorageException, DataProcessingException {
        final String token  = "token";
    try {
      return new URI(URIUtils.getAssetURI(azureStorageProperties.getProperty(StorageConstant.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)
        , cloudBlob).toString() + "?" + token);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      throw new DataProcessingException("Error while creating SAS URL " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
```

where **azureStorageProperties** is instance of **java.util.Properties**, which is created as bean and injected in class.

Now while writing unit test case , i am trying to mock Properties azureStorageProperties, i am getting below error:

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception.
```

Below is ss:
[image]

Below is class to be tested:

```
package com.company.ops.azure.storage;

import com.company.ops.azure.storage.constants.StorageConstant;
import com.company.ops.azure.storage.dto.CloudBlob;
import com.company.ops.cloudopsfacade.dto.SignedUrlDTO;
import com.company.ops.cloudopsfacade.exception.storage.CloudStorageException;
import com.company.ops.cloudopsfacade.exception.storage.DataProcessingException;
import com.company.ops.azure.storage.util.URIUtils;
import com.company.ops.cloudopsfacade.storage.ICloudStorageClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.SharedAccessBlobHeaders;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;


public class StorageClient implements ICloudStorageClient {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StorageClient.class);

  @Inject
  private CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient;

  @Inject
  Properties azureStorageProperties;

  @Inject
  private SASTokenGenerator sasTokenGenerator;

  private long sasUrlDuration;

  private Optional<String> sasUrlDurationKey;

  public StorageClient() {
    sasUrlDurationKey = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv(StorageConstant.SAS_URL_DURATION_KEY));

    if (sasUrlDurationKey.isPresent()) {
      try {
        sasUrlDuration = Integer.parseInt(sasUrlDurationKey.get());
      } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        LOG.debug("sasURLDurationKey invalid" + ex.getMessage());
        sasUrlDuration = StorageConstant.DEFAULT_SAS_URL_DURATION;
      }
    } else {
      sasUrlDuration = StorageConstant.DEFAULT_SAS_URL_DURATION;
    }
  }

  //NOTE: This constructor is just created for test case. As @Mock of final class is NOT supported in easymock
  public StorageClient(long sasUrlDuration, CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient) {
    this.sasUrlDuration = sasUrlDuration;
    this.cloudBlobClient = cloudBlobClient;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param containerName
   * @param blob
   * @param expiryTime
   * @return {@link URI}
   * @throws CloudStorageException
   * @throws DataProcessingException
   */
    private URI generateSASURI(String containerName,
                              String blob, Long expiryTime) throws CloudStorageException, DataProcessingException {
      CloudBlob cloudBlob = new CloudBlob(Optional.ofNullable(containerName)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CloudStorageException("container name is null")),
        Optional.ofNullable(blob).orElseThrow(() -> new CloudStorageException("blob name is null")));
      //@TODO: Need to check permissions: Currently create and write assigned
      final Set<SharedAccessBlobPermissions> permissions = EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.CREATE);
      final SharedAccessBlobHeaders contentHeaders = new SharedAccessBlobHeaders();
      //in case if duration need to set manually via api
      if (Optional.ofNullable(expiryTime).isPresent()) {
        sasUrlDuration = expiryTime;
      }

      sasTokenGenerator.sasTokenGeneratorInitializer(
        cloudBlobClient,
        cloudBlob,
        permissions,
        sasUrlDuration,
        contentHeaders);
      final String token  = sasTokenGenerator.getToken();
      try {
        return new URI(URIUtils.getAssetURI(azureStorageProperties.getProperty(StorageConstant.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)
          , cloudBlob).toString() + "?" + token);
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new DataProcessingException("Error while creating SAS URL " + e.getMessage(), e);
      }
    }

  /**
   *
   * @param containerName
   * @param blob
   * @param expiryTime
   * @return {@link URI}
   * @throws CloudStorageException
   * @throws DataProcessingException
   */
  @Override
  public SignedUrlDTO generateSignedUrl(String containerName, String blob, Long expiryTime)
      throws CloudStorageException, DataProcessingException, MalformedURLException {
    try {
        URI uri =  generateSASURI(containerName, blob, expiryTime);
        SignedUrlDTO signedUrlDTO = new SignedUrlDTO();
        signedUrlDTO.setSignedURL(uri.toURL());
        return signedUrlDTO;
    } catch (DataProcessingException ex) {
      LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
      throw ex;
    } catch (CloudStorageException ex) {
      LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
      throw ex;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      LOG.error("Unable to get URL");
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is complete code for UT

```
package com.company.ops.azure.storage;

import com.company.ops.azure.constants.AzureConstants;
import com.company.ops.azure.storage.constants.StorageConstant;
import com.company.ops.azure.storage.util.URIUtils;
import com.company.ops.cloudopsfacade.dto.SignedUrlDTO;
import com.company.ops.cloudopsfacade.exception.storage.CloudStorageException;
import com.company.ops.cloudopsfacade.exception.storage.DataProcessingException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import org.easymock.*;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;


@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class StorageClientTest extends EasyMockSupport {

  private CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient;

  @Mock
  private SASTokenGenerator sasTokenGenerator;

  @Mock
  private Properties azureStorageProperties;

  @Mock
  private StorageClient storageClient; /*= /*new StorageClient(StorageConstant.DEFAULT_SAS_URL_DURATION,
    cloudBlobClient, azureStorageProperties);*/

  @Before
  public void setup() throws URISyntaxException {
    resetAll();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    verifyAll();
  }

  @Test
  public void testGenerateSASURI() throws MalformedURLException, CloudStorageException, DataProcessingException {
    String containerName = "myprojectlocal";
    String blob = "testfile";
    Long expiryTime = 1000L;
    /*Properties azureStorageProperties = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Properties.class)
      .addMockedMethod("getProperty", String.class).createMock();*/
    //azureStorageProperties = new Properties();
   // azureStorageProperties.setProperty(StorageConstant.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, "storage-account-name");
    expect(azureStorageProperties.getProperty(StorageConstant.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)).andReturn("storage-account-name");
    expect(sasTokenGenerator.getToken()).andReturn("token");
    sasTokenGenerator.sasTokenGeneratorInitializer(anyObject(CloudBlobClient.class),
      anyObject(),
      anyObject(),
    anyLong(),
    anyObject());
    expectLastCall();
    //azureStorageProperties.getProperty(anyString()); //.andReturn("storage-account-name");
    //expectLastCall();
    //expect(azureStorageProperties.getProperty(StorageConstant.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)).andReturn("storage-account-name");
    replayAll();
    SignedUrlDTO signedUrlDTO  = storageClient.generateSignedUrl(containerName, blob, expiryTime);
    Assert.assertNotNull(signedUrlDTO);
  }

  private CloudBlobClient getCloudBlobClient() {
    final StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(TestConstants.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        TestConstants.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
    try {
      return new CloudBlobClient(URIUtils.getStorageAccountURI(TestConstants.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME), credentials);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your unit test code ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel added class with UT code

Comment: Does `azureStorageProperties.getProperty(StorageConstant.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)` actually throws an exception ? If so then you cannot mock it

Comment: no, it dont throw exception